# Entity field type symfony 2.0 - show data from database in edit action

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms

Here is the situation:

I have 3 tables (one-to-many):
Product, ProductLabel, LabelTag (Label is reserved -_-)

As you may have guessed, a product can have many labels.

Now I have a form product that shows the labels available. For my new and create actions I have been able to show and save the labels selected. 
My problem comes when I try to display labels + show selected labels in my edit action from database.

Some code:

**Entity Product:**

```
/**
 * @var Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection $productLabels
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Labeyrie\Bundle\MainsiteBundle\Entity\ProductLabel", mappedBy="product")
 */
protected $productLabels;
```

**Entity LabelTag:**

```
/**
 * @var Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection $productLabels
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Labeyrie\Bundle\MainsiteBundle\Entity\ProductLabel", mappedBy="labelTag")
 */
protected $productLabels;
```

**Entity ProductLabel:**

```
/**
 * @var Labeyrie\Bundle\MainsiteBundle\Entity\Product $product
 * 
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Labeyrie\Bundle\MainsiteBundle\Entity\Product", inversedBy="productLabels")
 */
protected $product;

/**
 * @var Labeyrie\Bundle\MainsiteBundle\Entity\LabelTag $labelTag
 * 
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Labeyrie\Bundle\MainsiteBundle\Entity\LabelTag", inversedBy="productLabels")
 */
protected $labelTag;
```

**Product Form:**

```
->add('productLabels', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'LabeyrieMainsiteBundle:LabelTag',
            'property' => 'title',
            'multiple' => true,
            'expanded' => true,
        ))
```

Here is how I saved it in **create action:**

```
if ($form->isValid()) {
        /* save product */
        $em->persist($product);
        $em->flush();

        /* save product labels */
        $labels = $product->getProductLabels();
        if (!empty($labels)) {
            foreach ($labels as $label) {
                $productLabel = new ProductLabel();
                $productLabel->setLabelTag($label);
                $productLabel->setProduct($product);

                $em->persist($productLabel);
            }
        }
        $em->flush();
    }
```

No problem with that.

Problem is in my **edit action:**

```
$entity = $em->getRepository('MyProjectBundle:Product')->find($id));   

    $form = $this->createForm(new ProductType(), $entity);
```

If I simply render the form, I will only see the labels, the information that which ones have been selected is not transmitted (since it is in the middle table that I manage) and thus not shown.

I need a solution to this using my one-to-many architecture. Is the form configuration wrong? Please help. :)

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer:

Simply need to do the following:

```
    $collection = new ArrayCollection();
    $labels = $entity->getProductLabels();
    if (!empty($labels)) {
        foreach ($labels as $label) {
            $collection->add($label->getLabelTag());
        }
    }

    $form->get('productLabels')->setData($collection);
```

Retrieve individual object (LabelTag), put it in an array collection, pass the collection to the form field's data and you are done.

The form is displayed and the selected options are shown.